# Why the checkbox is unchecked?

Tags: php, html

Please help me regarding the problem specified in the title.

The checkbox code is given below:

```
 <input name="accurate" type="checkbox"  <?php if (isset($qry_event['accurate'])) { echo  
 'value="checked"'; }?>>
```

It is to be noted that the 'accurate' field of the particular row of the table is set to 1.

Comment: Replace `value="checked"` with a plain `checked` (no quotes, no value).

Comment: @RobW: That's invalid HTML. Any time the checked attribute is specified, the only valid value is checked. It has to be `checked="checked"`.

Comment: @RobW you should post that as an answer. :) A more complete answer would be: the attribute `checked` defines if the checkbox is 'on' or 'off' and `value` will determine what is submitted if it is checked. If you don't define a value, it will be `ON`. @animuson it's a boolean attribute, in HTML, it's optional (not in XHTML).

Comment: @animuson: It's invalid XHTML. In both HTML4 and HTML5 it's perfectly fine.

Answer (score 5):

it should be `checked="checked"` or plain `checked`

```
<input name="accurate" type="checkbox"  
       <?php if (isset($qry_event['accurate'])) {
         echo 'checked="checked"'; }?> >
```

[`Reference`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/Input)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input name="accurate" type="checkbox"  <?php if (isset($qry_event['accurate'])) { echo 'value="checked" checked'; }?>>
```

It could simply be `checked` then add `value=checked` if you want that to be the value of that checkbox when submitted.

Answer (score 0):

In Static Page (HTML) THE BELOW HTML-Code's Work right.

`<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />`

Or

`<input type="checkbox" checked />`

if your check Box is not Checked, its due to your Condition ( if (isset($qry_event['accurate']))  ).

!Check Your Condition Exactly !